# Как найти текст по регулярному выражению

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, текст

Имеется текст html страницы. 
Как из всего кода html страницы извлечь все id элементов?
id выглядят так:

```
data-id="false_79136598548-1586258964@g.us_E3B3SDH74F91K83AB65334080CE5AA8A_79135896258@c.us"
```

Может кто в регулярные выражения?

Comment: `re.findall(r'data-id="(.+?)"', text)`

Comment: спасибо, работает. Но почему-то не выводит без 'data-id='

Comment: Если data-id тоже нужно, то нужно убрать скобки

Comment: выводит без него. Убрал скобки как ты и советовал, получилось.

Answer (score -1):

```
re.findall(r'data-id=".+?"', text)
```

спасибо [insolor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/1365/insolor)